# Compile Error trying to bind a ABBYY RTR SDK.AAR file via Xamarin Android Binding project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, abbyy

I get the error below when I try to bind the "abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.aar" downloaded from https://rtrsdk.com/#RTR.Android.Online using Xamarin Android Binding project in Visual Studio 2017, by following the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

```
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    CS0234    The type or namespace name 'IRecognitionContextHolder' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Abbyy.Mobile.Ocr4' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    AbbyLib    C:\_MyLab\Xamarin\My\OCR\TextRecogniser\AbbyLib\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Abbyy.Mobile.Ocr4.IRecognitionManager.cs    481    Active

Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    CS0738    'IDataCaptureServiceInvoker' does not implement interface member 'IRecognitionService.ExtendedSettings'. 'IDataCaptureServiceInvoker.ExtendedSettings' cannot implement 'IRecognitionService.ExtendedSettings' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IRecognitionServiceExtendedSettings'.    AbbyLib    C:\_MyLab\Xamarin\My\OCR\TextRecogniser\AbbyLib\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Abbyy.Mobile.Rtr.IDataCaptureService.cs    679    Active

Error    CS0738    'ITextCaptureServiceInvoker' does not implement interface member 'IRecognitionService.ExtendedSettings'. 'ITextCaptureServiceInvoker.ExtendedSettings' cannot implement 'IRecognitionService.ExtendedSettings' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IRecognitionServiceExtendedSettings'.    AbbyLib    C:\_MyLab\Xamarin\My\OCR\TextRecogniser\AbbyLib\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Abbyy.Mobile.Rtr.ITextCaptureService.cs    681    Active
```

**Update**

Steps I use by following the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

1 Add "abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.aar" under Jars folder

2 Set Build Action to LibraryProjectZip

3 Set Compile Using Android version: to Android 4.4 (KitKat) for the Binding project

4 Build the project

I get the errors above.

**Below is the versions of IDE:**

Window 7

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (2)
Version 15.8.6
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.6+28010.2041
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03062

Xamarin 4.11.0.776
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer 4.15.9
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates 1.1.116
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK 9.0.0.19
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 12.0.0.15
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: Are you getting this error while building the binding project or the Android project?

Comment: when I am building the binding project. I updated the post with my steps.

Comment: Did you create the .aar file? I assume that the aar file uses a third party jar file.

Comment: The .aar file is a "abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.aar" file downloaded from https://rtrsdk.com/#RTR.Android.Online for Android.

Comment: So it might be the problem with aar file.

Comment: I posted the same question on Xamarin, but it works for someone else. STRANGE. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141286/compile-error-trying-to-bind-a-abbyy-rtr-sdk-aar-file-via-xamarin-android-binding-project#latest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182410/discussion-between-hashimks-and-pingpong).